# How can assign value to ng-init with conditional expression?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init, ng-init

I want to assign variable in ng-init with conditional expression but it's not working with my code. I need to assign isCollapsed value true false with conditional expression.

```
<a class="email" ng-init="isCollapsed = (emailData.length>0?'true':'false')"></a>
```

Comment: which angular version you are using?

Comment: this code is working in angularjs 1.7.8

Comment: The `ng-init` directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`. This is not one of them.

Comment: I tried this its working but in angularjs 1.2 and above
I tried same in angularjs 1.1 but it did work. So may be version issue it is. If you tell us which version you are using we can help you with other approach. @Jaydeep Shah

Answer (score -1):

try this -

```
<div ng-init=" isCollapsed = ( emailData.length>10 ) ? true : false">
```